# Json dependencies NPM update- How fix vulnerabilities manually

Tags: node.js, security, npm, dependencies, package.json

I have lost 1 day in order to try to fix manually fews high vulnerabilities.
It was a waste of time.

I've read many post, blog and suggestion but I was unable to fix the problem.

Basically /css-what require an update to version 5.0.1 and the npm audit is telling that

```
│ Dependency of │ gulp-imagemin [dev]  
                                    
│ Path          │ gulp-imagemin > imagemin-svgo > svgo > css-select > 
                | css-what
```

I've run (on gulp-imagemin) the command `npm update`, then navigate to the next folder (imagemin-svgo) and again `npm update` etc etc. When I arrive to the css-what root, I run again `npm update` but it doesn't do anything;

Then I modified my package.json according

```
"resolutions": {
"trim-newlines": "^4.0.1",
"css-what": "^5.0.1",
"scripts": {
  "preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions"
}
```

}

I went back to the main root to run `npm i` but it doesn't amended all branches;
Besides when I run `npm ls css-what` or `npm ls trim-newlines` I can see that the new version has been installed on the node_modules but older version still unchanged on the tree

[root/tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a646w.png)

I was following https://hackernoon.com/how-fix-security-vulnerabilities-in-npm-dependencies-in-3-minutes-rq9g3y7u post but it doesn't worked for some reason, most probably my inexperience.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

To fix vulnerability you can try :

```sh
npm audit -fix
```

To update you can also use [npm-check-updates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates)

Comment: Hi, npm audit fix did not fixed anything, i forgot to add it to my post. Thanks

Comment: try install `npm-check-updates` and type `ncu -u gulp-imagemin` and finish with `npm i`.

Comment: Or if you want to update all packages you type `ncu -u`

Comment: After this command you type `npm i`. try this to see.

Comment: Hi Sega, thanks for yours suggestion. I've ran all commands on all the tree. Referencing to the image, I've tried on gulp-sass folder, on meow's folder and on the same trim-newlines. It looks that all dependencies are up to date but when I go to the main folder and run npm ls trim-newlines, the version still the old one...

Answer (score 0):

`npm update css-what` worked for me